# How to implement DDD and Repository Design Pattern for a Remote data store and a local one?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories, domain-model

I am new to DDD and the Repository Design Pattern thing, in fact I have no experience whatsoever on this. I came across it a while back and although I don't fully understand it yet I feel it's really flexible and I should give it a try. So I am working on this new Xamarin.Forms project and I'd like to implement this. The app involves fetching data from google firebase and persisting these data in the local database. Now from what I have read about repository pattern, ***the repository just serves as an abstraction of the actual data stores so that the client code has no idea how the persistence  and fetching of data is done, so this way it is possible to change the data source/store without breaking the client code***(please correct me if I am wrong). The first issue I came across was how to define my models, I read a lot of articles online on how to define models in DDD but all they do is talk and talk and talk with no specific answer, **should my model definition mirror how my data is stored on firebase or how I am going to persist it on the local sqlite db?.** This question was bugging me for a while then I realized both ways are wrong the domain model should have no relationship with how it is persisted, unless it is a persistence model, so I went online to read up on **Domain Model and Persistence Model** again and I got more talks. The bottom line is, can someone explain to me in simple terms with examples how to separate the domain model from its persistence model and how to design the repos for the two data stores, would I have one repo for the local one and another for the firebase one, then when and how do I work with the domain and persistence model?

Answer (score 1):

In a perfect world you don't need a persistence model at all. How you persist your domain model is just an implementation details, and you should not worry about it when you build the domain model in the first place.
Of course, in practice you cannot really adhere to this principle 100% of the time.

> should my model definition mirror how my data is stored on firebase

You may have a model with a one-to-one mapping to the data store. That's the Persistance Model for you. Usually is just an anemic propriety bag, full of setter and getter. And the point of the persistence model is that it's just an implementation details. You don't expose that to the user. You don't return it from any repositories.

Your concrete implementation of the repository will create and use the persistence model to save and retrieve data from the store. That's its only responsability. You should do this only if your tools (most likely an ORM) don't allow you to do otherwise.

At this point, you can:

1. *Encapsulate the persistence model into the domain model.* You can do this inside the repository, as the repository will alway and only return the domain model. Your domain model can deal with the persistence model, and hide this complexity away from the client.

   To be honest, I find this solution really ugly, as the domain model must be aware of the persistence model in the first place.
2. *Map from the persistence model to the domain model.* You will need to needs to map the individual fields/proprieties in the persistence to the domain object. This may be time consuming, because usually this mean that you will need to create the domain model yourself ( inside the repository ) from the persistence model, and viceversa, but will give a clean separation between domain and persistence.

Comment: thank you, option 2 sounds way better but I am still kinda lost on how to implement this. I don't mind code examples.  Should my repository for the google firebase data store be separate from that of the local sqlite db? if yes then in a way I will have to define two persistence models(one for sqlite db and the other for firebase) for each domain model. Am i right??

Answer (score 0):

> please correct me if I am wrong

Your basic idea is correct; Evans originally described the repository as a way of providing the illusion of an in memory collection.  That is to say, the client doesn't talk directly to the persistence component; it talks to *something* that implements the repository api, and that implementation is responsible for the details of storage.

> The bottom line is, can someone explain to me in simple terms with examples how to separate the domain model from its persistence model

It may help to re-affirm the basic motivation: we're trying to keep the domain model and the persistent model different, because they tend to change on different schedules -- we don't want to have to migrate the *database* every time we change the in memory representation of state.

The idea, then, is that we have two functions available in the repository

- one takes the domain's in memory representation, and converts it to the form that gets stored
- the other takes the stored form, and converts it to the in memory representation.

Often, the persisted form will have the characteristics of a message (being sent from the past to the present).  It's common to use a sort of message builder approach when converting the persisted form to the current model used by the domain (the domain logic provides the builder, which has a stable api, but not necessarily a stable implementation).